# Automatically remove R6 object

Tags: r, oop, finalizer, r6

I have created a bank account class with the R6 package . It has a balance that is private (not accessible after generation) and methods to withdraw and deposit a certain amount as well as a print method. (Hadley Wickham 14.3.3)

```
BankAccount <- R6::R6Class("BankAccount", public = list(
  # Functions to withdraw and deposit.
  deposit = function(amount){
    private$balance <- private$balance + amount
  },
  withdraw = function(amount){
    if (amount < private$balance){
    private$balance <- private$balance - amount
    }
    else {
      stop("Amount withdrawn is greater than available balance by", -(private$balance - amount))
    }
  },
  initialize = function(initial_balance){
    private$balance <- initial_balance
  },
  print = function(){
    cat("Bank balance is equal to", private$balance)
  }
  ),
  private = list(
    balance = NULL
  )
)
```

Currently, if I create a new R6 object and call the withdraw function with an amount greater than its initial balance, the function will stop and print a message. Instead, I would like the newly created object to be directly removed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to "remove" the (account?) object, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: It would be nice for simulation purposes, to keep track of the numbers of accounts surviving for example (it is a bit sloppy, but hope you get the point)

Comment: Objects do not "destruct" theirselves but when no no more reference to an object exists the finalizer function is called once the object is garbage collected (which in non-deterministic). So you have to use another method to count the number of accounts that have a positive account value eg. by adding a function `HasPositiveBalance`. How do you maintain the references to all class instances created by `BankAccount$new`. If you have a container object for that (eg. a list or vector) it should be quite easy to count the surviving objects by removing the other ones...

Comment: So please add a minimal client code example to your question to give us a chance to provide good answers. THX :-)